# dynamically changing the color of pie charts on Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, data-science, pentaho-report-designer

there is an excel file which contains chart number, segment number and their respective colors. So i want to change the color of reports on Pentaho Report Designer through the excel file means each segment of pie chart gets the color mentioned in excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Chart Property called Series Color where you can define the colors as per your need.

Comment: @ALIRAZAL1S13BSCS0131 multiple options to achieve one functionality, i have described one of the option.